# Is there a OpenAPI/Swagger spec for the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: discussion, api

I'm interested in calling the Stack Exchange API (https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) and was wondering if there is a [OpenAPI](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification)/[Swagger](https://swagger.io/) 2.0 or 3.0 specification for it? I didn't see it on the docs page but was wondering if one existed.

Comment: Used to generate a client with openapi-generator. Good work! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've started to create a spec here. It is far from complete but provides a project to work off of.

- https://github.com/grokify/api-specs/tree/master/stackexchange/

The spec can be used with Swagger UI here:

- https://petstore.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openapis/api-specs/master/stackexchange/stackexchange-api-v2.2_openapi-v3.0.yaml

Feel free to use and contribute.

Comment: Links are no good

Comment: Sorry for that. Try now.